# Get winform size after mouse up to get final size after resize

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to grab the windows size of a form when the mouse has been released. I can use the event SizeChanged but I put a test in there and it fires off numerous times before the mouse is released. I put in a counter and it was up over a 100 hits on a simple resize. I want to save this 'final' size to a config but I don't want it saving 100 times in a row.

An example of what I mean:

```
private void CreditCardScreen_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Size = Properties.Settings.Default.ScreenSize;
}

private void CreditCardScreen_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  count++;
  Console.WriteLine("Count: " + count);
  // save size here
}
```

I end up with:

```
..
Count: 66
Count: 67
Count: 68
Count: 69
Count: 70
Count: 71
Count: 72
Count: 73
Count: 74
```

How do I get the final window size after they have released the mouse after resizing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the job:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Point p = new Point();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.ResizeEnd += Form1_ResizeEnd;
            SetDimension();
        }

        void SetDimension()
        {
            p = new Point(this.Width, this.Height);
        }

        void Form1_ResizeEnd(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //check to avoid save if form was just moved...
            if (this.Width != p.X || this.Height != p.Y)
            {
                SetDimension();
                MessageBox.Show( string.Format("Width={0} Height={1}, save your settings!", this.Width, this.Height));
            }        
        }

}
```

Comment: I looked through the events several times looking for something like this, I'm not sure why I overlooked it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Form.ResizeEnd Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.resizeend(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The ResizeEnd event is raised when the user finishes resizing a form, typically by dragging one of the borders or the sizing grip located on the lower-right corner of the form, and then releasing it. For more information about the resizing operation, see the ResizeBegin event.